# integrating google's GTM iphone testing framework with XCode 4

Tags: unit-testing, xcode4, google-toolbox-for-mac

We have decided that GTM seems to be better than the integrated XCode 4 octest framework, but is there anyway to link a GTM target to the run pulldown button so we can press 'Test' (shortcut CMD U) and run our GTM stuff instead of the other one?